# Minikube keeps failing on creation : StartHost failed, but will try again: creating host: create host timed out in 120.000000 seconds

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, minikube

I've created a Switch in `Hyper-V Manager`  :

```
Virtual Switch Manager (on the right) => New Virtual Network Switch => External => MinikubeSwitch
```

[image]

And then :

[image]

After hitting in CLI (under Administrator in Windows 10) the line :

```
    minikube start --driver=hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch=MinikubeSwitch

I got : 

    PS C:\bin> minikube start --driver=hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch=MinikubeSwitch
* minikube v1.9.2 on Microsoft Windows 10 Pro 10.0.18363 Build 18363

* Using the hyperv driver based on user configuration                                                                                                                                           

* Starting control plane node m01 in cluster minikube                                                                                                                                           

* Creating hyperv VM (CPUs=2, Memory=2200MB, Disk=20000MB) ...                                                                                                                                  ! StartHost failed, but will try again: creating host: create host timed out in 120.000000 seconds                                                                                              

* Stopping "minikube" in hyperv ...                                                                                                                                                             

* Powering off "minikube" via SSH ...

* Deleting "minikube" in hyperv ...


    E0421 12:59:59.746863    2736 main.go:106] libmachine: [stderr =====>] : Hyper-V\Get-VM : Hyper-V was unable to find a virtual machine with name "minikube".
    At line:1 char:3
    + ( Hyper-V\Get-VM minikube ).state                                                                                                                                                             +   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                                                                                                                                         + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (minikube:String) [Get-VM], VirtualizationException                                                                                                  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidParameter,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.GetVM                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    E0421 13:00:01.624914    2736 main.go:106] libmachine: [stderr =====>] : Hyper-V\Get-VM : Hyper-V was unable to find a virtual machine with name "minikube".
    At line:1 char:3
    + ( Hyper-V\Get-VM minikube ).state                                                                                                                                                             +   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                                                                                                                                         + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (minikube:String) [Get-VM], VirtualizationException                                                                                                  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidParameter,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.GetVM                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    E0421 13:00:03.443467    2736 main.go:106] libmachine: [stderr =====>] : Hyper-V\Get-VM : Hyper-V was unable to find a virtual machine with name "minikube".
    At line:1 char:3
    + ( Hyper-V\Get-VM minikube ).state                                                                                                                                                             +   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                                                                                                                                         + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (minikube:String) [Get-VM], VirtualizationException                                                                                                  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidParameter,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.GetVM                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    * Creating hyperv VM (CPUs=2, Memory=2200MB, Disk=20000MB) ...
    E0421 13:00:05.635939    2736 main.go:106] libmachine: [stderr =====>] : Hyper-V\Get-VM : Hyper-V was unable to find a virtual machine with name "minikube".
    At line:1 char:3
    + ( Hyper-V\Get-VM minikube ).state
    +   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (minikube:String) [Get-VM], VirtualizationException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidParameter,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.GetVM


    E0421 13:00:07.748572    2736 main.go:106] libmachine: [stderr =====>] : Hyper-V\Get-VM : Hyper-V was unable to find a virtual machine with name "minikube".
    At line:1 char:3
    + ( Hyper-V\Get-VM minikube ).state
    +   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (minikube:String) [Get-VM], VirtualizationException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidParameter,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.GetVM


    E0421 13:00:09.940572    2736 main.go:106] libmachine: [stderr =====>] : Hyper-V\Get-VM : Hyper-V was unable to find a virtual machine with name "minikube".
    At line:1 char:3
    + ( Hyper-V\Get-VM minikube ).state
    +   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (minikube:String) [Get-VM], VirtualizationException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidParameter,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.GetVM


    E0421 13:00:11.850044    2736 main.go:106] libmachine: [stderr =====>] : Hyper-V\Get-VM : Hyper-V was unable to find a virtual machine with name "minikube".
    At line:1 char:3
    + ( Hyper-V\Get-VM minikube ).state
    +   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (minikube:String) [Get-VM], VirtualizationException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidParameter,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.GetVM


    E0421 13:00:13.887769    2736 main.go:106] libmachine: [stderr =====>] : Hyper-V\Get-VM : Hyper-V was unable to find a virtual machine with name "minikube".
    At line:1 char:3
    + ( Hyper-V\Get-VM minikube ).state
    +   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (minikube:String) [Get-VM], VirtualizationException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidParameter,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.GetVM


    E0421 13:00:16.088700    2736 main.go:106] libmachine: [stderr =====>] : Hyper-V\Get-VM : Hyper-V was unable to find a virtual machine with name "minikube".
    At line:1 char:3
    + ( Hyper-V\Get-VM minikube ).state
    +   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (minikube:String) [Get-VM], VirtualizationException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidParameter,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.GetVM


    PS C:\bin> Get-Vm                                                                                                                                                                               
    Name            State   CPUUsage(%) MemoryAssigned(M) Uptime           Status             Version
    ----            -----   ----------- ----------------- ------           ------             -------
    DockerDesktopVM Running 0           2048              02:16:40.4550000 Operating normally 9.0


    PS C:\bin>
```

However it keeps failing , even though I've tried to delete the old minikube and reinstall it.

Any idea how to fix it ?

Answer (score 4):

OK , found the problem , I put it below for other people whom might encounter the same problem :

Replace the CLI command

```
minikube start --driver=hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch=MinikubeSwitch
```

with :

```
 minikube start --driver=hyperv MinikubeSwitch
```

The param `--hyperv-virtual-switch` is not relevant anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Please run below commands in command prompt in admin mode.

```
minikube delete --all --purge
minikube start
```

Comment: run `cmd` `admin` mode solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on a freshly installed Windows 10.
Before starting minikube, docker must be installed (if docker is going to be used as driver), hence I had to delete minikube, and then re-install it.

This way minikube automatically found docker and used docker as the driver
`Automatically selected the docker driver. Other choices: hyperv, ssh`.

to delete minikube:

```
minikube delete
```

and then again

```
minikube start
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you couldn't manage to fix the issue you can follow the [minikube docs for HyperV driver](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/hyperv/).

> This is valid only for Windows10 Pro users.

You can verify that it says:

```
--hyperv-virtual-switch: ... Defaults to first found
```

And as I could see in the screenshots you already have a Default switch so there is no need to create a new one you will only need to run `make sure to run as admin`:

```sh
minikube start --driver=hyperv
```

In case you had some issue you can try to delete with purge flag the minikube VM then restart it:

```sh
minikube delete --all --purge
```

else you could troubleshoot running:

```sh
minikube start --alsologtostderr -v=7
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with mac, found that docker was not running. I started the docker desktop and then deleted minikube and installed again.

```
    minikube delete
    minikube start
    minikube dashboard
```